Power BI DAX Transpose function
My current data is available in below format:
Product Date        Age bucket  Deliv_qty   Max_qty_PerPeriod
A       05/01/2024  3Months     100         200
B       05/02/2024  3Months     200         200
C       05/03/2024  3Months     150         200
A       08/04/2024  1Months     110         130
B       08/05/2024  1Months     130         130
A       02/10/2024  6Months     250         350
B       02/11/2024  6Months     350         350
C       01/01/2020  12Months    125         125

I would like to convert the data into below format:

I tried this:
JoinedT =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALCULATETABLE (
        SUMMARIZE (
            DailyMasterData,
            DailyMasterData[Symbol],
            DailyMasterData[Date],
            DailyMasterData[Age_bucket],
            DailyMasterData[DELIV_QTY]
        )
    ),
    "1-MonthMAX",
        CALCULATE (
            MAX ( DTable[Max_Qty_PerPeriod] ),
            ALLEXCEPT ( DTable, DTable[Symbol], DTable[Age_bucket] ),
            FILTER ( DTable, DTable[Age_bucket] = "1-month" )
        )
)

The expected output :
Product Date    Deliv_qty   1Months MaxQty  3Months MaxQty  6Months_MaxQty  12Months MaxQty
A               05/01/2024  100     130     200             350             125
B               05/02/2024  200     130     200             350             125
C               05/03/2024  150     130     200             350             125
A               08/04/2024  110     130     200             350             125
B               08/05/2024  130     130     200             350             125
A               02/10/2024  250     130     200             350             125
B               02/11/2024  350     130     200             350             125
C               01/01/2020  125     130     200             350             125

I would like to fill my 1-month column which is coming as BLANK as per below picture:


You need 2 calculated columns before creating your calculated table:
1Months_MaxQty = 
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( DailyMasterData[Max_qty_PerPeriod] ),
    FILTER ( DailyMasterData, DailyMasterData[Age bucket] = "1Months" )
)

3Months_MaxQty = 
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( DailyMasterData[Max_qty_PerPeriod] ),
    FILTER ( DailyMasterData, DailyMasterData[Age bucket] = "3Months" )
)

Then modify your JoinedT like below:
JoinedT = 
SUMMARIZE (
    DailyMasterData,
    DailyMasterData[Product],
    DailyMasterData[Date],
    "Deliv_qty", SUM(DailyMasterData[Deliv_qty]),
    "1Months_MaxQty", MAX(DailyMasterData[1Months_MaxQty]),
    "3Months_MaxQty", MAX(DailyMasterData[3Months_MaxQty])
)



Create directly a calculated table:
TransformedTable = 
VAR Max1Months = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('DailyMasterData'[Max_qty_PerPeriod]),
        'DailyMasterData'[Age bucket] = "1Months"
    )
VAR Max3Months = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('DailyMasterData'[Max_qty_PerPeriod]),
        'DailyMasterData'[Age bucket] = "3Months"
    )
VAR Max6Months = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('DailyMasterData'[Max_qty_PerPeriod]),
        'DailyMasterData'[Age bucket] = "6Months"
    )
VAR Max12Months = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('DailyMasterData'[Max_qty_PerPeriod]),
        'DailyMasterData'[Age bucket] = "12Months"
    )

RETURN
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        'DailyMasterData',
        "Product", 'DailyMasterData'[Product],
        "Date", 'DailyMasterData'[Date],
        "Deliv_qty", 'DailyMasterData'[Deliv_qty],
        "1Months MaxQty", IF(ISBLANK(Max1Months), 0, Max1Months),
        "3Months MaxQty", IF(ISBLANK(Max3Months), 0, Max3Months),
        "6Months MaxQty", IF(ISBLANK(Max6Months), 0, Max6Months),
        "12Months MaxQty", IF(ISBLANK(Max12Months), 0, Max12Months)
    )



Sorry. I made slight changes to my dataset, please have a look once again please.
